# Converting multiple try/except blocks into a function

Tags: python, function, try-catch

This is more a general programming question than related to the actual code.

I have this ugly code that takes an input from JIRA and converts it from milliseconds to hours written out multiple times like below:

```
def convertMillis(ms):
    hours = ms / 1000 / 60 / 60
    return hours

try:
    newaccsla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10705.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    newaccsla_comp = np.nan
try:
    newaccsla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10705.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    newaccsla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    paymentssla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10136.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    paymentssla_comp = np.nan
try:
    paymentssla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10136.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    paymentssla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    modifysla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10713.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    modifysla_comp = np.nan
try:
    modifysla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10713.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    modifysla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    MFsla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10711.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    MFsla_comp = np.nan
try:
    MFsla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10711.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    MFsla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    closeaccsla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10140.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    closeaccsla_comp = np.nan
try:
    closeaccsla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10140.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    closeaccsla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    casla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10213.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    casla_comp = np.nan
try:
    casla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10213.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    casla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    at_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10144.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    at_comp = np.nan
try:
    at_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10144.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    at_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    modfeesla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10134.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    modfeesla_comp = np.nan
try:
    modfeesla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10134.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    modfeesla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    tdsla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_11200.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    tdsla_comp = np.nan
try:
    tdsla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_11200.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    tdsla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    querysla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10142.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    querysla_comp = np.nan
try:
    querysla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_10142.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    querysla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    recsla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_15600.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    recsla_comp = np.nan
try:
    recsla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_15600.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    recsla_ongoing = np.nan

try:
    reportsla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_15601.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
except:
    reportsla_comp = np.nan
try:
    reportsla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.customfield_15601.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
except:
    reportsla_ongoing = np.nan
```

I would be comfortable doing something like taking all the custom fields, putting them in one list then doing a for over the function like this:

```
field_list = ['customfield_10705','customfield_10136','customfield_10713','customfield_10711','customfield_10140','customfield_10213','customfield_10144','customfield_10134','customfield_11200','customfield_10142','customfield_15600','customfield_15601']


  def get_jira_hours(field):
        try:
            newaccsla_comp = convertMillis(issues.fields.field.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
        except:
            newaccsla_comp = np.nan
        try:
            newaccsla_ongoing = convertMillis(issues.fields.field.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
        except:
            newaccsla_ongoing = np.nan

for field in field_list:
    get_jira_hours(field)
```

However there is three variables that are linked to each function call that I need to iterate over - the `customfield_10705` and the name to save each try/except too `newaccsla_comp` and `newaccsla_ongoing`.

Here's the variables in order.. ie. `field_list[0]` is linked to `name_list[0]`

```
field_list = ['customfield_10705','customfield_10136','customfield_10713','customfield_10711','customfield_10140','customfield_10213','customfield_10144','customfield_10134','customfield_11200','customfield_10142','customfield_15600','customfield_15601']

name_list = ['newaccsla','paymentssla','modifysla','MFsla','closeaccsla','casla','at','modfeesla','tdsla','querysla','recsla','reportssla']
```

Best way to iterate over these? Thanks.

Comment: What part of your expression is raising the exception? It's usually a bad idea to have a non-specific `except` block, rather than one that only catches the kinds of exceptions you're expecting (since it can coverup bugs, such as a typo in your code that causes an exception to always be raised).

Comment: It's pretty old code that I wrote when I was a complete (even more than now) beginner that I'm trying to refactor - the exception is that `ongoingCycle` and `completedCycle[0]` likely just do not exist. -- For context I'm looping this over ~40,000 issues and capturing the relevant ongoing/completed cycle (one of, both or none) for each issue. Each issue likely contains only one ongoing/completed pair out of the 12 above - again some may not exist at all. It's a messy dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can turn each of those four-line blocks into a one-liner if you just edit your `convertMillis` function to return `np.nan` instead of raising—or, if you can't do that, wrap the function in another one:

```
def convertMillisOrNan(millis):
    try:
        return convertMillis(millis)
    except:
        return np.nan

newaccsla_comp = convertMillisOrNan(issues.fields.customfield_10705.completedCycles[0].remainingTime.millis)
newaccsla_ongoing = convertMillisOrNan(issues.fields.customfield_10705.ongoingCycle.remainingTime.millis)
# etc.
```

---

Or, maybe the exception you're trying to handle comes a bit farther up. You're always calling `convertMillis` on `<something>.remainingTime.millis`. What if, say, the field always exists, and always has an `ongoingCycle`, but that doesn't always have a `remainingTime` attribute? Then you can push that part into the `try:`, and also simplify things even further at the same time:

```
def convertCycle(cycle):
    try:
        return convertMillis(cycle.remainingTime.millis)
    except:
        return np.nan
newaccsla_comp = convertCycle(issues.fields.customfield_10705.completedCycles[0])
newaccsla_ongoing = convertCycle(issues.fields.customfield_10705.ongoingCycle)
```

---

If the exception comes even higher up—e.g., if the field doesn't always have an `ongoingCycle`—obviously you need to push more of the expression inside the `try:` block; I'm really just making a guess here at what you're trying to handle with that `except:`.

---

And, while you're at it, do you really want a bare `except:`? That will handle any exception, not just an `AttributeError` or `ValueError` or whatever kind of exception you were actually expecting.

---

Meanwhile, your existing `jira_hours` refactor doesn't work because you can't just use `.field` when `field` is a variable holding a string. One way to solve that is:

```
def get_jira_hours(field):
    comp = convertCycle(field.completedCycles[0])
    ongoing = convertCycle(field.ongoingCycle)
    return comp, ongoing

newaccsla_comp, newaccsla_ongoing = get_jira_hours(issues.fields.customfield_10705)
paymentssla_comp, paymentssla_ongoing = get_jira_hours(issues.fields.customfield_10136)
# etc.
```

Another way to solve it is with `getattr`—which I'll show below.

---

But you can do even better. Do you really need these all to be independent variables, rather than, say, items in a dict?

```
fieldmap = {
    'newaccsla': 'customfield_10136',
    'paymentssla': 'customfield_10705',
    # etc.
}

values = {}
for fieldname, customfieldname in fieldmap.items():
    field = getattr(issues.fields, customfieldname)
    comp, ongoing = get_jira_hours(field)
    values[f'{fieldname}_comp'] = comp
    values[f'{fieldname}_ongoing'] = ongoing
```

Now, instead of using `newaccsla_comp`, you have to use `values['newaccsla_comp']`. But I suspect your code is actually going to be doing a lot of code where you copy and paste the same thing for each variable, which you can replace with code that just loops over the dict.

But if you really do need these to be independent variables—which, again, you probably doing—you can do the same thing by just using `globals()` or `locals()` instead of `values`.

On the other hand, if you're going to be repeating yourself over comp/ongoing pairs of values, just store the pairs in the dict: `values[fieldname] = comp, ongoing`.

Also, since all of the custom field names seem to be `customfield_NNNNN`, you can simplify things even further, by mapping `'newaccsla': 10136`, etc., and then doing `getattr(issue.fields, f'customfield_{customfield}')`.

Comment: Ok this is obviously an amazing post and I'm trying to digest it all. To add additional information while I'm going through it.. It's possible to have neither `ongoingCycle` or `completedCycle` be filled and both need to return `np.nan`.
- Do I need a bare except? Probably not, but that's all I know how to do right now.
- Also I am indeed going to be reusing these variables for other purposes (ex. using all names to create a dataframe) so the dict makes sense, though I haven't reached that yet.

Comment: Rather than a bare `except`, specify the exception types that you'd expect to be raised (e.g. `AttributeError`). If you need to catch multiple exception types, you can specify a parenthesized tuple of them (e.g. `except (AttributeError, IndexError):` or whatever).